# Query date from same column with several conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to do a query to see when a client is disconnected, between January and February, by a cable company and if they got connect again until 7 days after the disconnection.

My table would be something like this:

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| client  | ID_Order | Work_Order | Date_Order |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| Client1 | 123AB    | Disconnect | 20/01/2017 |
| Client1 | 234EA    | Connect    | 22/01/2017 |
| Client2 | 242FA    | Connect    | 30/01/2017 |
| Client3 | 244FE    | Disconnect | 30/01/2017 |
| Client2 | 301EA    | Disconnect | 10/02/2017 |
| Client4 | 355AD    | Disconnect | 20/02/2017 |
| Client4 | 368AD    | Connect    | 25/02/2017 |
| Client5 | 401AD    | Connect    | 05/03/2017 |
| Client6 | 440AD    | Disconnect | 15/03/2017 |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

And I want to transform the previous table in a table like this: one row per client, with the connect order and disconnect order in 2 different columns

```
+---------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| client  | ID_Order_Discon | Date_Discon | ID_Order_Con |  Date_Con  |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| Client1 | 123AB           | 20/01/2017  | 234EA        | 22/01/2017 |
| Client4 | 355AD           | 20/02/2017  | 368AD        | 25/02/2017 |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

My problem:
1- How make the query inside the same columns (Date_Order), to choose the clients that where connected after 7 days the disconnection. Guess need to use `DATEDIFF()`?
2- how to put the orders of the same client in 2 different columns? Guess I have to do an IF()/CASE () and a join ()?

Comment: What do you require in cases where a client has disconnected / connected / disconnected / connected ?

Comment: @O.Jones thanks for editing my tables :) . 

If a client as more than one disconnected/connected i only want to see the case where the different between the disconnected/connected is less than 7days. 

If there is more than one case in this situation i want to see the most recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Combine both table you can use:

```
select c1.client, cq.ID_Order ID_Order_Discon , c1.Date_Order as Date_discon, c2.ID_Order  ID_Order_Con, c2.Date_order Date_Con  
from table c1 join table c2 on t1.client = t2.client and t1.work-order = 'disconnect' and t2.work_order = 'Connect'
```

and for the frst question you can use `where DATEDIFF(c1.date_order,c2.dateOrder)>7`

Comment: I'm going to try it, send you feedback after (can't today).